# Programming the LED in USRP2

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

Is it possible to the Software Programm the LED's of the USRP2 ?

At the moment I am using the Interrupt mechanism (Using IRQ's) and reading servicing these interrupts in the firmware.

I am looking at a way, if I can program the LEDs in the FPGA code.

I understand the LEDS have some pre-defined functionality. I could use the LEDS which are not being used.

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Controlling the LEDs is really simple!  It's all done in the FPGA code, and it is just a matter of setting the pins low or high.

Open up the Verilog and find where they are controlled.  It is a simple change, and you'll just need to rebuild the FPGA code with the Xilinx toolchain.

Note, though, that if you aren't comfortable working with FPGA tools, this isn't easy to accomplish.